Interactive grid not updating validations if save button is clicked more than once after new rows inserted
I am on Oracle Apex 22. I have an issue with my IG. For my grid, I validate some of the columns that are simple type="Column is not null" and that "Display inline and in notification".
When I first load the page, if I add rows with missing values in the columns, click save, the cells get highlighted in red and the errors show up in the yellow notification box as expected:

Now, if I don't fix these errors, and I instead click 'Add Row' to add more rows, and leave them empty, I expect all the rows to have a red highlighted cell. What is happening is instead, only the rows from the first save are highlighted in red, and the new rows inserted do not have any errors around them. So I first added, 3 rows, now I have added 2 rows in the picture, and only the first 3 rows are highlighted:

When I click save, I get the error pop-up "Correct errors before saving." I am not sure why this is happening. I would like to it for every time the save button is pressed, it goes through all the rows and validates them and displays errors.

Are you using custom validation or value required attribute for columns? What is the scope of your process: Only for created and added rows or all submitted rows?

I am using Oracle Apex validations with type ="Column is not null" for all the columns. I have tried both Only for created and added rows and all submitted rows. I have also tried different combinations of turning off 'always execute' for the validations and for the columns themselves, I have tried both turning on/off  "value required". Nothing has worked.
